# How can I pass an entire file as an argument to a tcl script?

Tags: file, tcl

I have a script say, myscript.tcl. The script will go through a file and do some basic operations. But I dont want to hardcode the file name inside the script with something like "open myfile.txt". I want to be able to pass different files to the script from the command line while running. How do I achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the arguments to tclsh after the script filename are stored as a list in the global Tcl variable, `argv` (and the length of that list is put in `argc`; you don't need that because Tcl lists know their own length). This means that you can then use normal list processing commands such as `lindex`, `lassign` or `foreach` to access the values in that list:

```
set filename [lindex $argv 0]
puts "The filename is \"$filename\""

set f [open $filename]
set line [read $f]
puts "The first line of \"$filename\" is \"$line\""
```

Answer (score 4):

Call the script with `tclsh myscript.tcl myfile.txt` and in the script:

```
lassign $argv filename
set fid [open $filename]
```

If you want to pass several filenames: `tclsh myscript.tcl file1 file2 file3`

```
foreach filename $argv {
    puts "Operating on: $filename"
    set fid [open $filename]
    # ...
}
```